# Inline CSS file for custom email template in custom module not loading

Tags: email, css, email-templates, less-css, magento2.2.0

I'm using Magento version 2.2.0 to create a custom email template for my custom extension, I need to add inline CSS to the email template, I've followed the instruction [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html) , so my email template file look like this:

```
<!--@subject Custom E-mail  @-->
<!--@vars {
"var this.getUrl($store, 'admin')":"Warehouse Account URL",
"var customer.email":"Customer Email",
"var customer.name":"Customer Name"
} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}} <!-- pathe of template header-->


{{inlinecss file="css/email-inline.css"}}

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting"> {{trans 'Dear %dear,' dear=$dear |raw}} </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <p> {{var message |raw}} </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{var content |raw}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}} <!--footer of template-->
```

My file location for CSS code

> app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/web/css/email-inline.less

Answer (score 1):

You can get more idea by following below link.

https://gordonlesti.com/magento-2-email-template-style-directives/

Also, do the below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this step you done or not. But Please run these commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f 
php bin/magento indexer:reindex 
php bin/magento cache:flush 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

I think file is no loaded because of static content was not deployed.

Hope this will help you.